# Adjustment object not a widget type GtkBuilder

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I can't use `Gtk::Adjustment` widget from my glade file. The program builds and runs with the following error:

```sh
(test-glade-spinbutton:227780): gtkmm-CRITICAL **: 13:38:45.769: gtkmm: object `adjustment_width' (type=`gtkmm__GtkAdjustment') (in GtkBuilder file) is not a widget type.

(test-glade-spinbutton:227780): gtkmm-CRITICAL **: 13:38:45.769: gtkmm: Gtk::Builder: widget `adjustment_width' was not found in the GtkBuilder file, or the specified part of it.

** (test-glade-spinbutton:227780): CRITICAL **: 13:38:45.769: Gtk::Builder::get_widget(): dynamic_cast<> failed.
```

However, for this post I've removed interaction with `Gtk::Adjustment` so the program can actually run. The program crashes if I try to read my adjustment widget's current value.

Below is the C++ code:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>

using Gtk::Adjustment;
using Gtk::Application;
using Gtk::Builder;
using Gtk::Grid;
using Gtk::SpinButton;
using Gtk::Window;

class MyWindow : public Window
{
    Grid       *main_content;
    Adjustment *adjustment_width;
    SpinButton *width;

public:
    MyWindow()
    {
        auto builder = Builder::create_from_file("test-spinbutton.glade");

        builder->get_widget("main_content"    , main_content);
        builder->get_widget("adjustment_width", adjustment_width);
        builder->get_widget("width"           , width);

        add(*main_content);

        present();
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto app = Application::create("domain.reverse.test-spinbutton");

    MyWindow hello;

    return app->run(hello);
}
```

and the glade file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_height">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="upper">2147483647</property>
    <property name="value">1</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_width">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="upper">2147483647</property>
    <property name="value">1</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkGrid" id="main_content">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLabel">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="margin_left">24</property>
        <property name="margin_top">6</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Width</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="left_attach">0</property>
        <property name="top_attach">1</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLabel">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="margin_left">24</property>
        <property name="margin_top">6</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Height</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="left_attach">0</property>
        <property name="top_attach">2</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="width">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="margin_left">6</property>
        <property name="margin_top">6</property>
        <property name="hexpand">True</property>
        <property name="adjustment">adjustment_width</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="left_attach">1</property>
        <property name="top_attach">1</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="height">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="margin_left">6</property>
        <property name="margin_top">6</property>
        <property name="hexpand">True</property>
        <property name="adjustment">adjustment_height</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="left_attach">1</property>
        <property name="top_attach">2</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLabel">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Image Size</property>
        <attributes>
          <attribute name="weight" value="bold"/>
        </attributes>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="left_attach">0</property>
        <property name="top_attach">0</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkToggleButton" id="toggle_ratio_wh">
        <property name="label">gtk-execute</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
        <property name="margin_left">6</property>
        <property name="margin_top">6</property>
        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
        <property name="always_show_image">True</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="left_attach">2</property>
        <property name="top_attach">1</property>
        <property name="height">2</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <style>
      <class name="dialog-main-content"/>
    </style>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem, great sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that `adjustment_width` is not a widget, like its [inheritance tree](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Adjustment.html) suggest (unlike a grid or a spin button) so `get_widget` won't work. You need to use [`get_object`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Builder.html#a2e2dfd63721cf7dd648e262ed6630f0c). For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

using Gtk::Adjustment;
using Gtk::Application;
using Gtk::Builder;
using Gtk::Grid;
using Gtk::SpinButton;
using Gtk::Window;

class MyWindow : public Window
{
    Grid       *main_content;
    SpinButton *width;
    
    Glib::RefPtr<Adjustment> adjustment_width;

public:
    MyWindow()
    {
        auto builder = Builder::create_from_file("test-spinbutton.glade");

        // Widgets:
        builder->get_widget("main_content"    , main_content);
        builder->get_widget("width"           , width);

        // Other objects (non widgets):

        // 1. Get the object from the object three:
        Glib::RefPtr<Glib::Object> adjustmentObject = builder->get_object("adjustment_width");

        // 2. At this point, it is a Glib::Object (which is Adjustment's base type), so we need
        //    to cast:
        adjustment_width = Glib::RefPtr<Adjustment>::cast_dynamic(adjustmentObject);

        // 3. Then we can access it normally:
        std::cout << "The adjustment value is : " << adjustment_width->get_value() << std::endl;

        add(*main_content);

        present();
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto app = Application::create("domain.reverse.test-spinbutton");

    MyWindow hello;

    return app->run(hello);
}
```

Comment: All widgets below started with `<object>` tag including `Gtk::Adjustment`... so the warning message didn't ring the right bell on my head LOL. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: No problem. You are right, this is misleading.